# Open two windows with two iOS projects

Tags: xcode

How can I open two windows with two different projects in Xcode? 
Having two windows open must ease to drag and drop files from one project to the other.

Answer (score 18):

Use **File/Open** (<kbd>⌘O</kbd>) to open a project in another window.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, be sure to un-maximize the window by hovering on top left and touching the green button (if presently maximized). If you use Command+T then afterwards you can drag that tab into the desktop space to make a new window. Then you can open your other project. Then be sure to unmaximize it as well. Then you can use Fn+drag to copy files and storyboard from one prpject to the other. Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

I am using xcode 9.2 and it has default like you said i.e. when we open a new project it will attach itself with the current window. 
OR you can try (Command+T) to open a new tab then open project manually.